# Updating.. message label not showing when running a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a long running process in my website and so I've set up a thread which provides a Label with a message "Updating, please wait.." while the process is running. the thread is set up as below

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreatePartsExcelFile));
t1.Start();

while (t1.IsAlive)
```

The method CreatePartsExcelFile runs and I did think about using MessageEventHandler but instead I've just used the code

```
StatusLabel.Visible = true;
StatusLabel.Text = "Updating, please wait..";
```

The process runs and completes ok but the message never appears, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do any exceptions get thrown?

Comment: No exceptions, and I've checked to make sure that the code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run those two lines outside the thread. You aren't going to be able to access the label from the background thread. Normally, when dealing with status updates from a background thread there's a more complex approach because you send more than one, but in your case it's extremely simple (and that's not a jab, there's something to be said about simplicity) because you just want to let the user know you're updating. So, set those two lines just before the start:

```
StatusLabel.Visible = true;
StatusLabel.Text = "Updating, please wait..";
t1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
StatusLabel.Visible = true;
StatusLabel.Text = "Updating, please wait..";
StatusLabel.Refresh();
```

Comment: Using Refresh() returns the error 'System.Web.UI.Controls.Label does not contain a definition for Refresh.'

Comment: You can use Background worker for this issue, before calling the background worker DoWork event you can set the label as "Updating, please wait.." and in RunWorkerCompleted event you can chane the label, because after work completed the background worker calls the RunWorkerCompleted event

Comment: System.Web.UI.Controls.Label does not contain a definition for Refresh is new to me,will check it